# Combining vector indexes and queries

Tags: r

I want to select the first 5 elements of a vector *and* those that are greater that a certain threshold. For example:

```
v = c(10, 11, 2, 8, 5, 2, 10)
v[1:5] # return the first 5 elements
v[which(v>5)] # returns all elements > 5
```

How do I combine the two queries to return 10, 11, 2, 8, 5, 10? That is the first 5 elements, plus 10 because greater than 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `union`

```
union(v[1:5], v[which(v>5)])
```

Or as commented by @Vlo (in case there are duplicate values)

```
v[union(1:5, which(v>5))]
```

Comment: Depending on what OP wants, but `union` on number doesn't deal with duplicated values. `union` on index does: `v[union(1:5, which(v>5))]`

Comment: @Vlo Thanks for the comments, I didn't think about it.